# Redirect button to view in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

I have a login and a signup page. I want that after clicking on the login or signup button, the user is redirected to another view which will be a micropost.

The code for the signup page is as follows. (as in the form part) -

```
   <h2 class="text-center">Sign Up</h2>
                <%= form_for(input_output_SignUp_url) do |f| %> 
                <%= f.label :first_name,"First name:" %>
                <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

                <%= f.label :last_name,"Last name:" %>
                <%=f.text_field :last_name %>

                <%= f.label :email,"Email:" %>
                <%= f.email_field :email %>

                <%= f.label :phone,"Phone no:"%>
                <%= f.text_field :phone %>

                <%= f.label :city,"City:" %>
                <%= f.text_field :city %>

                <%= f.label :addr_1,"Address 1:" %>
                <%=f.text_field :addr_1 %>

                <%= f.label :addr_2,"Address 2:" %>
                <%= f.text_field :addr_2 %>

                <%= f.label :state,"State:"%>
                <%= f.text_field :state %>

                <%= f.label :postal_code,"Postal Code:"%>
                <%= f.text_field :postal_code %>

                <%= f.label :password,"Password:"%>
                <%= f.password_field :password %>

                <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation:" %>
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= button_to "View profile", input_output_micropost_path%>
            <% end %>
```

Now this isn't working. When I click on the button, it shows an error- **No route matches [POST] "/input_output/SignUp"**

The routes file is as follows:-

```
   root 'static_pages#home'

   get 'static_pages/home'
   get 'static_pages/genre'
   get 'static_pages/accessories'
   get 'static_pages/contactus'
   get 'static_pages/aboutus'

   get 'input_output/Login'
   get 'input_output/SignUp'
   get 'input_output/micropost'

   get '/genre', to: 'static_pages#genre' 
   get '/accessories', to: 'static_pages#accessories'
   get '/aboutus', to: 'static_pages#aboutus'
   get 'contactus', to: 'static_pages#contactus'

   get 'Home', to: 'static_pages#home'
   get '/Login', to: 'input_output#Login' 
   get '/micropost', to: 'input_output#micropost'
   get '/SignUp', to: 'input_output#SignUp'
end
```

How can I make this error go away?

Edit:- As asked, this is the result of *rake routes*
/home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

/home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated

/home/gauri/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:138: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

rake aborted!

ArgumentError: Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes.

/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/config/routes.rb:25:in `block in '

/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/config/routes.rb:1:in `'

/home/gauri/Academics/CS/Ruby on Rails/ScholarShip/ScholarShip/config/environment.rb:5:in `'

Tasks: TOP => routes => environment

Comment: To what view do you want to link? Please run `rake routes` and post the output.

Comment: All your routes are "get" requests.  You need to add a route, that will "post" the data from the form to a controller and action you're looking to process it in.  For ex.  post 'input_output/SignUp'

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla I want to link it to the view called 'micropost' which is part of the controller called InputOutput which also contains the Sign Up page and Login page.

Comment: @bkunzi01 I'm not quite sure what the exact format of the "post" route should be. As stated in the previous comment, the view that I want the button to direct to is called "micropost". So how should I be framing this?

Comment: What is the name of the controller and the controller's action that point to this view?  All Rails views are associated to a controller and an action within that controller.  Tell us that and we can give you the route.  I'd highly recommend some tutorials on Rails Routing.

Comment: @bkunzi01 is rigth, you need to add something like `post '/micropost' => "input_output#micropost"` to your route file.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla the error after adding that to the route file is the same as before : **No route matches [POST] "/input_output/SignUp"**

Comment: @bkunzi01 the name of the controller is InputOutput. It's actions are SignUp, Login and micropost. If you can recommend any rails routing tutorials, I would be grateful because my brain is far too scattered right now and I feel as if I'm all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

The top part of your routes are wrong, the route must point to a controller and action inside the controller, so the routes should be something like:

```
   root to: 'static_pages#home'
   get '/genre', to: 'static_pages#genre' 
   get '/accessories', to: 'static_pages#accessories'
   get '/aboutus', to: 'static_pages#aboutus'
   get '/contactus', to: 'static_pages#contactus'

   get '/Home', to: 'static_pages#home'
   get '/Login', to: 'input_output#Login' 
   get '/micropost', to: 'input_output#micropost'
   get '/SignUp', to: 'input_output#SignUp'
   get '/Home', to: 'static_pages#home'
   get '/Login', to: 'input_output#Login' 
   get '/micropost', to: 'input_output#micropost'
  ##################################################
  #### Action for the form is set as post, so signup
  #### must be a post route
  ##################################################
   post '/SignUp', to: 'input_output#SignUp'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. Instead of

```
<%= button_to "View profile", input_output_micropost_path%>
```

Make that a submit

```
<%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

Then in your controller in the create action add a redirect at the end. Something like this

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to input_output_micropost_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Edit:
You need RESTful routes for your user model. If you are putting that under the input_output namespace it would be something like this

```
resources :input_outputs do
  resources :users
end
```

I recommend the Rails Tutorial book by Michael Hardt. It shows how to do something like this in very good detail. It's a classic.